# When setting UITapGestureRecognizer delegate run time error occurs in main.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, delegates, spritebuilder

This problem has been frustrating me for quite some hours. I basically have a game where I need to use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but if there is a CCButton on screen, this tap gesture overrides a tap on the button. In order to get past this problem, I implement the method listed below in my code `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer`. In order for this to be recognized, I have to set the `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s delegate to `self` (at least as far as I know).

My button works fine on its own, no bugs. Without declaring the delegate of the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, the taps are recorded perfectly and everything works, no bugs (I just can't click on the CCButton then). When I implement this all together and set the delegate and do the following, I get a bug. I enter my `LevelScene`, tap my mainMenu button which brings me back to my main menu, then click my play button again, and then my app crashes with *Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0xe000000c)* in my `main.m` file.

I'm not sure why this is happening, and additionally I am using Spritebuilder, but I'm not sure if that would affect anything. Below is the relevant code (my `Grid` is added to my `LevelScene` through Spritebuilder). Sorry the code is long but I think it's all necessary.

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        //error occurs right below this line
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

**LevelScene.m**

```
@implementation LevelScene {
    Grid *_grid;
}

- (void)mainMenuFromLevelScene {
    [[LevelManager sharedInstance] reset];
    CCScene *levelScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:levelScene];
}


@end
```

**Grid.m**

```
@implementation Grid

- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    UITapGestureRecognizer * gridTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gridTapped)];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:gridTapped];
    gridTapped.delegate = self;
}

- (void)gridTapped {
    //correctly logs Grid tapped when screen is tapped
    CCLOG(@"Grid tapped");
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    //everything works correctly here too
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];    
    if ((touchLocation.y < 0 || levelWonBool)) {
        CCLOG(@"returning no");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Grid.h**

```
#import "CCNodeColor.h"

@interface Grid : CCNodeColor <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end
```

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Thanks, was able to solve it after going through this =)